# Spotlight disappeared when I updated

Tags: macos, software-update, spotlight

Last night my computer said that it needed an update, so I ran it. This AM the spotlight icon is gone! How do I get it back? Thank you!

EDIT: I'm told that the question was unclear. I mean that the little icon in the upper-right that looks like a magnifying glass was gone today. I ran an update last night, so I thought maybe that had something to do with it. However, this issue is now resolved, because after asking this question I tried to restart my computer and couldn't, and force quit wasn't even opening, so I realized there were bigger problems. I forced my computer to restart, and now spotlight is back! Thanks I guess! (:

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. please edit this to include your OS and version and perhaps a better description of which of the various spotlight icons are missing. A screen shot or picture from a cell phone might help us help you more rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

If the icon is gone, you can still start a search by   `cmd + space`?

If that doesn't work, you'll need to troubleshoot things a bit and post back with some more details.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201516